# How to output an object into a dynamically changing table based from Object given

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to output an object that has been formed from a websocket API response. Currently i have some code that outputs the last result of this object. I am looking to develop on method i have to create a table that will show all "prices" from the object not just the last price in the list. The code for splitting up the object can be found here:

```
for(i in Object.keys(dataObj)){
console.log(Object.keys(dataObj)[i])
}
```

This then is called down into this section of code which will look to iterate new rows based on unique data. E.g. Based on the prices held in the Obj. I'm looking to create a table that reacts accordingly live to what is contained within the object. The code for this can be found below:

```
var mainObj = [
        {  
        price: Object.keys(dataObj)[i],
        }
    ];
    var k = '<tbody>'
    for(i = 0;i < mainObj.length; i++){
        k+= '<tr>';
        k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i].price + '</td>';
        k+= '</tr>';
    }
    k+='</tbody>';
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
```

The variable k is then called up to the HTML into a tbody with the id "tableData".

Below you can see the output visually in my electron App.

[image]

Here you can see the corresponding console output.

[image]

Any advice on how i can iterate this set of responses into the table shown is welcomed.

Data Input:

[image]

Data Output:

[image]

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: Added current data input, expected output is a ladder of prices with their quantities.

Comment: Please add CODE not PICTURES of code!!!